# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor doesn't await for TimerTask termination

Tags: java, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

I have to solve a java problem that I am not able to solve by myself.

I have a basic class and a test class :

```
public class Appender extends SMTPAppender{

   private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

   private final class MyTask extends TimerTask{
      @Override
      public void run(){
         //some code
         append(myEvent)
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void append(ILoggingEvent event){
      //some code
      scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(task, cacheSize,    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

   @Override
   public synchronized void stop(){
      super.stop()
      scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
      scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(cacheSize,    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

}
```

---

```
   public class AppenderTest {

       @Test
       public void myTest(){
          Appender appender = new Appender();

          methodWhichLogSomeLog(); // will call appender.append()

          appender.stop();

          //some test code
       }

    }
```

I am waiting for that my ***appender.stop()*** overrided has to wait for my ***ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor*** and its scheduled ***TimerTask***.

Actually, my ***appender.stop()*** doesn't wait for this scheduled task and I don't know why. It seems to be the ***awaitTermination()*** role.

Comment: How do you know that ??:>

Comment: Because in debug, the main thread continu to process and doesn't wait for the new thread (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) which has to terminate after TimerTask schedule.

Comment: Are you sure? Since we are talking about concurrent execution, task could finish when you were stepping (if you are holding only 1 thread insteed of all). Also I am not sure how it should behave as awaitTerminatiion waits unitl currently queued tasks are finished. Its possible that scheduled tasks are not counted as "queued" due its undetermined delay.

Comment: Thing is that my ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor (size 1), is :

**t** - Initialize.....
**t1** - Scheduled --> schedule(myTask, 3000, milliseconds).....
**t2** - Code reach scheduleThreadPool.shutdown() AND scheduleThreadPool.awaitForTermination() **before** myTask (TimerTask) start.....
**t3** - Error in my test because not enough data collected because of myTask didn't send event that it shall send.

Comment: If you shutdown the pool, scheduled tasks wont start. You will have to wait for it to start if you need that.

Comment: Ok! Then, I don't identify any way to do what I want... Event CountDownLatch is not usefull here...

Comment: You could use it to block before pool.shutdown until task is executed (once)

Comment: SOLUTION : It could not works because of synchronized stop() method. If in main thread, stop is call before (or at same time) than end scheduled task, concurrent access.

In my case, was @override of SMTPAppender from logback wich is synchronized (don't know why)....

Hope this could help someone...